# Trigger event when option element selected (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript

This question has been asked many times, but all the answers I've seen use jQuery, which I CAN'T use for this project. I am trying to execute code when option element "Other" has been selected from a list inside a select element.

Using "change" as the event doesn't seem to work.

```js
document.querySelector("#title").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  if (event.target.textContent === "Other") {
    console.log("Other Selected");
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="title" name="movie_title">
    <option value="titanic">Titanic</option>
    <option value="avatar">Avatar</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event.target.value

```js
document.getElementById("title").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<select id="title" name="movie_title">
       <option value="titanic">Titanic</option>
       <option value="avatar">Avatar</option>
       <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `onchange` event that triggers every time the select option changed:

```js
function myfunction(value) {
  console.log("changed to "+value+"!")
}
```

```html
<select onchange="myfunction(this.value)" id="title" name="movie_title">
   <option value="titanic">Titanic</option>
   <option value="avatar">Avatar</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

One other solution could be to add an `event listener`:

```
document.getElementById("title").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  // run your code
});
```

```js
document.getElementById("title").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  console.log("changed to: " + event.target.value + "!");
});
```

```html
<select id="title" name="movie_title">
   <option value="titanic">Titanic</option>
   <option value="avatar">Avatar</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use event.target.value , instead of textContent which will be providing all options instead of selected option

```
document.querySelector("#title").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  if (event.target.value === "other") {
    console.log("Other Selected");
  }
});
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JLoNMK?editors=1010